# File Manipulation, codeigniter and image_lib.php config file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to do image manipulation using codeigniter, and I would like to save configuration in a config file. For all the manipulation functions, most of the config remains same except for a few things, for example new_image, source_image etc.

So how can I save some configuration in the config file and still provide other when actually calling one of the functions of the image library ?

**EDIT**: This scenario can actually be applied to other codeigniter libraries too which support custom config file auto loading, for example upload library.

Comment: Which functions would that be? Do they automagically use the config or can you pass parameters? Can you easily extends those classes and plug in your own code?

Comment: @m02ph3u5 You can provide the config as array when loading the class, like this : $this->load->library('image_lib', $config); And if the config are saved in the config file, then you don't need to pass the $config to the load function

Comment: Ain't there no way to hot-swap the configs loaded? I'd be suprised.

Comment: You can make your own config file (i.e. `APPPATH . 'image.php'`) and autoload it.

Comment: @m02ph3u5 I can load the the config in the calling script and pass it when loading the class or to initialize() class function, but that would defeat the purpose of having them variables in a separate file.

Comment: One suggestion would be to extend the image library with a `MY_Image_lib` file. I work successfully having an extended image library for many projects. Inside you can set some different setups easily, making customized methods pre-configured.

Comment: @jtheman I don't think that would work, I will still have to do the initialization in the extended class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one possible way to achieve it. Most of the properties of the class Image_lib are non static public properties, therefore we can access them with the class object.

So simply set them after the class initialization and before calling any function of the class.

**application/config/image_lib.php**

```
    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config['source_image'] = '/path/to/image/mypic.jpg';
    $config['new_image'] = '/path/to/image/mypic.jpg';

    /*** Have some Default values for the required properties ***/
    $config['width'] = 75;
    $config['height'] = 50;
```

**In your Model**

```
    $this->load->library ( 'image_lib' );

    $config [ 'source_image' ] = $directory_path . '\\' . $value;
    $config [ 'new_image' ] = $thumbnails . '\\' . $value;

    /*** set properties manually ***/
    $this->image_lib->width = 100;
    $this->image_lib->height = 100;

    if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize (  ) ) return FALSE;
```